# Java. Не вызывается метод супер-класса из дочернего

Tags: java, ооп

Нужна помощь не вызывается метод супер-класса из дочернего..

О коде:

Этот код - несколько складов которые принимают какие-то продукты, и когда `NoIceboxWarehouse` переполняется(9 максимально хранит) то дальше все продукты идут в `NoIceboxReserveWarehouse`. На сам Warehouse обращать внимание не стоит так как он был создан когда условия о том что склад может переполнится не существовало. А тут я как раз должен добавить такое расширение что-бы это стало возможно, но так, что-бы не сломались старые тесты.

У меня несколько классов в цепочке наследования я пытаюсь из дочернего вызвать метод родительского:

Родительский:

```
public class Warehouse implements Repo {

    /**
     * List contain products.
     */
    protected ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "warehouse";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAppropriate(Product product) {
        return (product.checkQuality() < 26);
    }
}
```

Вот его наследник:

```
public class NoIceboxWarehouse extends Warehouse {



    /**
     * This repo contain only 9 products, all next after 9, go in NoIceboxReserveWarehouse.
     * @return "" if filling equal 10 products.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAppropriate(Product product) {
        return  this.products.size() < 9 &&
                (product.checkQuality() < 26) &&
                this.checkIceFlag(product);
    }

    private boolean checkIceFlag(Product product) {
        return !product.getFlag().equals("ice") &&
                !product.getFlag().equals("canReproduce");
    }
}
```

И еще подуровень:

```
public class NoIceboxReserveWarehouse extends NoIceboxWarehouse {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NoIceboxReserveWarehouse";
    }

    /**
     * Check base repo reached the limit.
     * @param product product for check.
     * @return result base repo limit and product quality.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAppropriate(Product product) {
        // вот тут проблема: 
        // >>return super.getProducts.size() > 8<< ...
        return ControlQuality.getNoIceboxWarehouse().getProducts()
                .size() > 8 && (product.checkQuality() < 26);
    }
}
```

В последнем классе в методе `isAppropriate(Product product)` я хочу проверить состояние родительского объекта `NoIceboxWarehouse` такой записью(она у меня закоментирована в коде) : `super.getProduct.size() > 8` но все время получаю нули приходится лезть в класс который хранит эти репозитории создавать статические указатели и по ним выдергивать состояние:

```
ControlQuality.getNoIceboxWarehouse().getProducts().size() > 8
```

Я хочу как то поизящнее это сделать но что-то не получается почему `super` не работает? Это потому что он не знает какой конкретно экземпляр я имею в виду?

Можно как-то получить доступ к полю класса не обращаясь к тому месту где создается объект этого класса, через наследование или еще как-то? Вот помогите пожалуйста советом, что я не так понимаю?

Comment: super всегда "знает", к какой реализации по иерархии вверх следует обращаться - в java нет ромбовидного наследования(на которое вы, как я понимаю, намекаете), так что эта проблема неуместна. Реализация есть в родительском классе родителя - Warehouse, так что будет вызван метод оттуда. Не ясно, что по-вашему значит "не работает".

Comment: Мне кажется супер вам тут совсем не нужен и можно просто getProduct.size() вызвать.

Comment: >>>Не ясно, что по-вашему значит "не работает"<<< Я имел в виду что я хочу вызвать через super метод родительского класса который был определен выше у его родителя.

Comment: @Павел, как раз этот метод и вызывается - больше просто нечему вызываться(в таблице виртуальных функций указатель на изначально переопределенную не изменялся в родителе-промежутке). Поэтому все еще не понятно, что у вас не работает(что за ошибка)?

Comment: А ну да! Дело в том что есть еще один класс ControlQuality который хранит объекты NoIceboxReserveWarehouse и NoIceboxWarehouse и мне надо следить за их состояниями сколько там уже добавленно продуктов. И когда я вызываю ControlQuality.getNoIceboxWarehouse().getProducts().size() мне показывает сколько продуктов правильно а когда вызываю super.getProducts() то он всегда возвращает 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, что я вижу. В классе `Warehouse` есть метод `getProducts()` а вызывается метод `getProduct()`. Либо у Вас опечатка в вопросе, либо есть два метода `getProducts()` и `getProducts()`

Далее, в классе `NoIceboxReserveWarehouse` метод `getProduct()` не переопределяется, соответственно `super` вообще не нужен

И наконец проверьте в методе `NoIceboxReserveWarehouse.isAppropriate()` что

```
ControlQuality.getNoIceboxWarehouse() == this
```

есть вероятность, что Вы работаете с разными объектами

Comment: getProduct() да это опечатка в вопросе

Comment: @Павел Еще одно предположение

Comment: да  в общем-то я уже проверил что ControlQuality.getNoIceboxWarehouse() == this - false просто я пытаю понять почему.